# What is the fastest way to copy files from remote location to local folder using ssis?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have 10k files in remote location(Unix path mounted in Windows) and need to copy in local folder. Currently it is taking more than 25 mins. Is there any way to achieve this in 10 mins? I tried using c# as well for copying but still no luck. Any other approach?

Comment: We may need some more info here. What is the method taking 25mn? What is the length of a simple copy (with explorer or PowerShell)? What is the size of the files? Do you need checksums? Also, by Unix path do you mean NFS (version?) or a SMB share on the Unix (protocol version too?)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looping over a list of files, I would try breaking the copy into parallel operations. SSIS Control Flow provides easy ways to co-ordinate parallel tasks.  Give each task a subset of the files to copy.  On modern servers, parallel execution can be 10x faster or more.

Or it could be you just have a weak network and that is as fast as it can go...